# Tabulate area tool's output results units?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, tabulate

I'm using ArcGIS DEsktop and I have tried to calculate the area of each different land cover class in a raster of 25m size in British National Grid coordinate system. To do that I used the tabulate area tool, but I'm not sure if the results are in square meters or just meters.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use Tabulate area tool in raster with resolutin 5 x 5m per pixel (EPSG: 5514 - Czech rep. Krovak East North coordinate system), the result is in square meters per zone. So it means in zone with only one pixel, result will be 25 square meters.